# Adding tags for graduate level/research level questions?

Tags: discussion

Recently, while browsing some questions of what we could label of graduate level, I began noticing some users who only answered those more advanced question. Other than that, they couldn't be considered very engaged in the community. I won't name users, because I think it would not be proper, and besides that's not the point of my question.

The point of my question is to in fact facilitate and promote their engagement in this community.

Why not create a graduate tag, and a research tag?In this way, those users would find it easier to search for questions they deem interesting.

I'll leave to you the details. This is just a simple suggestion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I see no problem with a 'graduate-research' tag. Separately they might be misapplied. (I am researching where to buy jeans for the lowest cost!)